# how to "skip" one parameter of a method with a default value letting it use it's default value, but change parameters after it

Tags: programming, variables

**lets say we have a function like this(fictional):**

```
function1(int Z, int X, bool Y=true, int Count=10, int ID=1,bool TeaTime=false);
```

And I want to run this function, but I want to change all parameters, except for "Count", and I want that to keep using it's default value.

**Disclaimer**
in this fictional case and in the real case where I faced it I found the default value in the header file and I manually coded it in. but I do not want that, at least not to rely on it, for example if the default value changes in the library then in my code it would still be forced to use that old value. also for ease of use and reducing the chance at problems/mistakes.

**What I tried:**
I already tried NULL and DEFAULT, both of them actually let my code work perfectly fine, but I made a test function which had such default values and printed the variables to the serial output and I found that using NULL actually overwrites it to 0 and DEFAULT overwrites it to 1.

I also tried some things like keeping one empty and such but those would give compile faults.

**in short:**

**is there a way to let one parameter somewhere in the middle of the parameters of a function use it's default value while still manually setting the later ones?**

Comment: No, you have to define everything until the last non default value you are passing. Everything after gets default values. You can make overloaded functions or you can pass the structure..

Comment: your question belongs at https://stackoverflow.com/questions ... it is a general programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most intuitive would be builder pattern with "chaining" ability (=returning reference to itself)

Something like (computer version, in arduino remove main, iostream and cout):

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomeParams {
    int        X;
    int        Z;
    bool       Y = true;
    int    count = 10;
    int       ID = 1;
    bool teaTime = false;

    SomeParams(int x, int z) : X{x}, Z{z} {};

    SomeParams & noY() { Y=false; return *this; }
    SomeParams & setCount(int c) { count = c; return *this; }
    SomeParams & setId(int i) { ID = i; return *this; }
    SomeParams & yesTeaTime() { teaTime = true; return *this; }
};

void function(SomeParams const & p) {
    std::cout << "X: " << p.X
              << " Y: " << p.Y 
              << " Z: " << p.Z 
              << " ID: " << p.ID 
              << " count: " << p.count 
              << " teaTime: " << p.teaTime 
              << "\n";
}

int main() {
    function(SomeParams{45,68}.yesTeaTime().setId(154758).noY());

    // without chaining:
    auto params = SomeParams{4457,5468};
    params.setCount(4515);
    params.setId(15);
    function(params);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, that would indeed work well. 
took a while to look how it works since I didn't code that much lately and then indexes tend to blend between languages in memory.
but this seems very usefull and fun for making more dynamic things.

however in my case the problem faced mostly was that in some normal libraries they had noting like this(just checked if there was), so instead of making better functions, I originally was looking for using existing ones better.

Comment: still I am happy, since I came to learn/get inspire with something new, and got that now, by learning something nice and interesting(I think I even sought for something like this some years ago)

Comment: Added other way without chaining (if you have those setters without returning reference to itself eg like: `void noY() { Y=false; }`)